# Property named "type" will not serialise with json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-web-api

Been scratching my head on this for a while so I thought I'd reach out.

We use a C# version of the ISO standard data types and in quite a few cases it implemented a property called

```
type
```

e.g.

```
    private EntityNamePartType typeField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Namespace="")]
    [DataMember(Name = "type", IsRequired = true)]
    public EntityNamePartType type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
```

Now, no matter what I do or which attributes I try using the Json.Net serialise used by default in webAPI, this field refuses to serialise.

If I used DataContractJsonSerialiser, the property serialises fine.

However, if I rename the property to "Type" it works, e.g.

```
private EntityNamePartType typeField;

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Namespace="")]
[DataMember(Name = "type", IsRequired = true)]
public EntityNamePartType Type
{
    get
    {
        return this.typeField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.typeField = value;
    }
}
```

So for some reason the json.net serialiser is ignoring properties called "type" (case sensitive)

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: I'm curious what your reason is for not adhering to C# casing conventions?

Comment: I believe it might be the case that the type is part of the implementation detail, but I think you can give the property a different name and with attributes specify what it will be named in serialization.

Comment: What is EntityNamePartType? Is it custom class implemented by you? Is that serializable?

Comment: Have you tried adding `[JsonProperty("type")]` to the property?